# Duas pessoas responderam certo, o que eu faço?

Tags: debate

Fiz essa pergunta : [Atributos de herdeiros com prototype não aparecem em reflection Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41974/atributos-de-herdeiros-com-prototype-n%C3%A3o-aparecem-em-reflection-javascript/42029#42029)

Acontece que entrei dois dias depois e havia duas respostas, as duas estão certas mas só posso atribuir a correta para uma delas.

O que seria justo fazer?

Comment: Escolha a que mais te agrada. Isso inclui não só estar correta, mas também a maneira como explica, como os exemplos dados se aplicam ao seu problema específico, etc.

Comment: Independente de qual escolher, vc sempre pode votar a favor de todas que de alguma forma foram úteis.

Comment: Escolha a do autor que tiver menos reputação. E sempre dê preferência para mulheres :D. Brincadeira, hehe... Podiam colocar uns emoticons aqui, mas só os básicos pra não poluir...

Comment: Se ambas tiverem o mesmo conteúdo, com a mesma riqueza de detalhes, me parece justo aceitar a resposta mais antiga e pontuar a outra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pessoalmente o meu modelo tende a ser o de alguma forma descrito pelo [@bfavaretto ♦](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2274/duas-pessoas-responderam-certo-o-que-eu-fa%C3%A7o?cb=1#comment7560_2274) nos comentários da pergunta, ou seja:

Quando uma ou mais respostas lidam de forma correta com o problema e podem ser consideradas uma solução para o mesmo, a resposta que:

- Fornece maior detalhe;
- Contém exemplo de código ou o código da pergunta com a solução aplicada;
- Explica o porque do problema bem como o porque da solução.

É sem duvida a resposta a ser aceite.

Para todas as outras, dou um voto positivo.